# Uncatchable HTML div

Tags: html, css

Although I know it's impossible, but yet, it's here. I have an uncatchable HTML div. I even tried to **exaggerate** with my CSS-selector, but I can't get a hold on this div...

Here is my CSS-selector:

```
html.js body.html div#page-wrapper div#page div#main-wrapper.clearfix div#main.clearfix div#sidebar-second.sidebar div.section div.region-sidebar-second div#block-ipdc-user-profiel.block-ipdc div.content {
    color: red;
}
```

Here is my div:
[image]

And yet, the color isn't turning red... What am I missing here?

Comment: Holy convoluted selector Batman!

Comment: tried the '!important' flag? Normally, 'div#block-ipdc-user-profiel div.content' should be sufficient too... Perhaps you have a live link to share?

Comment: Check if you have any other style that changes the color to another. In addition in Developer Tools you can see what CSS is currently apply and where they came from.

Comment: @codegrabber, yep I did. No result... I don't have a live link since it's a dev-site

Comment: What browser are you using? Can you post the HTML source on jsFiddle.net (or simular)?

Comment: sure you are including the css rule in that file ?

Comment: what should turn red? Could we please see whats inside your content div

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, please add this as an answer so I can accept this... I have like 20 css-files and I was indeed working in the wrong file. Oh, this is stupid!

Comment: @Michiel, 20 css-files .. :/ sounds like a nightmare .. :)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, sounds like Drupal and indeed... It's a nightmare!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code.

The specificity is so high that it is almost impossible to be overriden by anything else, except a `!important` rule.

You also need to make sure that this rule is ***indeed included in this page***..

---

Both scenarios can be verified by checking the style tab in firebug to see which rules actually affect the element..

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
#block-ipdc-user-profiel .content {
    color: red;
}
```

Since #block-ipdc-user-profiel is an id there should be only one on the page so the above CSS should be all that you need.

Comment: Nope, that's what I originally had. But it didn't work out...

Comment: Fair enough. Without looking through all your code I'm going to struggle to help you. As others have suggested, try adding !important to see if this works and make use of the CSS pane of Firebug. It can be very enlightening.

Comment: Try changing another property other than the color to see if you can get anything else to change. Add `font-weight:bold` for example. This will tell you if it's a problem with the selector or a problem with another style declaration overiding your `color` property.

Answer (score 2):

Try the simpliest one first and then and the other selector... until you see where you lose it.

```
.content {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should start with a much simpler selector and verify in the CSS pane of Firebug that it's being applied to that div.

Then check if it's being overriden by something else and check what's the priority of that othe rule (it might be using !important)

Comment: I used the `!important` flag, but with no result. A simple selector doesn't work, so I tried with an extreme large one. But it didn't work either...